# Calculate the last four row and subsequent same in mysql

Tags: mysql

I the file with four column name , year,period and amount. I want to make the query which add one column contain the sum of amount for last four quarter only. I want to achieve with select statement. Sample data as under.It total only if there is four quarter is available. And when fifty quarter is add it will total only last four quarter on each row.

```
company A    2005    1   -0.15    0
company A    2005    2    0.69    0
company A    2005    3    1.08    0
company A    2005    4    0.1     1.72
company A    2006    1    0.73    2.6
company A    2006    2    1.14    3.05
company b    2005    1    0.54    0
company b    2005    2    5.29    0
company b    2005    3    9.94    0
company b    2005    4   -3.04    12.73
company b    2006    1    6.85    19.04
company b    2006    2    5.52    19.27
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Can you explain periods 1,3,4,5 - is this a typo?

Comment: I make the table at the sql fiddle  as you suggest. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c606f/1

Comment: yes there is no 5 period in database. I made the correction in data. Period actually represent the quarter of the year

Comment: I don't get this line **And when fifty quarter is add it will total only last four quarter on each row**. What do you mean by fifty quarter? Quarter means they can be 4 or less, not more than 4 anyway.

Comment: Sorry as my English is not good. I just want last four quarter total. If you see the data sum it show last four quarter total. Irrespective of year. 
 if you look at the sum 2.6 it is the total of (  2005    2    0.69,  2005    3    1.08, 2005    4    0.1, 2006    1    0.73 ). It all together is last four quarter.

Comment: and if you look at 1.72 (it is the total of Last four quarter of 2005)

Comment: i have find the solution. I make the mysql function. Which return the profit sum. I called the function for each row of the database.